# how to identify "unused" Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We have approximately 2 dozen SQL Database in our Azure portal.  I have been asked to evaluate these and see if any are no longer being used and can be dropped.  I know how to query their original Quotas and current sizes but I am baffled as to how to query DTUs.

How can I query each DB and see when someone last logged into or initiated any queries?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following query should give you an idea if the database has been used based on resource consumption over the last 7 days:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
WHERE --database_name = 'AdventureWorksLT' AND
    end_time > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
ORDER BY end_time DESC;
```